# WARNING: makefile.in seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting

Tags: makefile, wxwidgets

While trying to configure WxWidgets 2.9.1 on Windows XP (32 bit) the configure script ended with this:

```
...
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: WARNING: Makefile.in seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
config.status: error: cannot find input file: contrib/Makefile.in
configure: error: ./configure failed for src/tiff
```

I made sure that mentioned Makefile.in is where it should be. I use MinGW32 for make.

I found [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/46882), I tried to translate it somehow to my situation (from Ubuntu to Windows), but it still returns the same error.

How should I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the warning is harmless and has nothing to do with the problem.

Second, the error itself is mysterious because the file `src/tiff/contrib/Makefile.in` does exist (or at least should, check if it didn't somehow disappear in your installation) but I think I already saw this before and things like this happen when you use files with DOS EOLs with Unix/Cygwin tools. Get the sources from `.tar.bz2` file and not `.zip` to fix this.

Finally, why do you use 2.9.1 released in 2010, I think? There is really no reason to not use 2.9.4...

Comment: I'm in the middle of making WxWidgets 2.9.4 extracted from .tar.bz2 file now. Make returns some error, but configure seems to have been finished without any errors. So the problem in question is solved. +1 and accepted.

Comment: Even better - WxWidgets 2.9.4 have been installed succesfully.